# set windows authentication login prompt count to one

Tags: authentication, iis, windows-authentication

is it possible to change the count of the login prompt of windows authentication?

by default when using Windows authentication, browser prompts for user credentials 3 times then returns an error page. is it possible to just set it to only one?

Comment: Because users *always* type their passwords correctly first time, every time?

Comment: yes. if the user has no access to the site but the credentials given is correct, he/she still needs to input those credentials over again before getting to the error page informing that no access was granted. So what I want is to inform the user the first time he/she input the credentials.

Comment: But I was pointing out (in a roundabout fashion) that it does it like that because *people* make mistakes sometimes when logging on. Its *browser* behaviour, they're used to it, and there's no way I'm aware of to change it.

Comment: I get your point, but it's not good to keep asking for username and password and not informing the user immediately what seems to be the problem.
Anyway, thanks for pointing that out :)